# How to use fontawesome light icons in my react-native application?

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I try to use Font Awesome Pro light icons in my react-native application.

I imported my necessary packages and add in library to my icon which I want to use.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faIgloo} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro';
...
//App.js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    library.add(faIgloo);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MainNavigator />
    </View>
    );
  }
}


//Slides.js where I want to show icon.
...
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
...
  renderSlides(){
        return(
            <View>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-igloo" />
            </View>);
        });
}
```

But the problem is, the prefix of icon is "fas" which means **'solid'**.How can I change this to **'light'** ?

Comment: you should use react-native-vector-icons for the best experience.

Comment: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/FONTAWESOME5.md this should help

Answer (score -1):

```js
import FontAwesome5Pro from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro';
   
const icon = <FontAwesome5Pro name={'comments'} light />;
```

Comment: 'light' is not an option in the current `react-native-vector-icons` implementation